# Capistrano deployment throws psych error: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1) :`safe_load'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, yaml, capistrano, psych

On my local machine the project works perfectly fine. Bundle install works fine and I can run the project locally. Till now, all my deployments were also working fine. But starting this deployment (no changes to any of the gems or even the code), even without changing existing code in any way, the deployment started breaking on bundle install with below error ->

```
Rails -> '5.0.7.2'
Ruby -> 2.5.3
Bundler             1.16.6
Deployment Tool -> Capistrano '3.11.0'
```

#<Thread:0x00007f9f6013bd00@/home/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
1: from /home/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute' /home/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in` rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as ruby@10.38.212.234: cd /var/www/portal.myapplication.com/releases/20220119150641; /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/wrappers/bundle install exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
cd /var/www/portal.myapplication.com/releases/20220119150641; /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/wrappers/bundle install stdout: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1)
```

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/psych-4.0.3/lib/psych.rb:323:in `safe_load' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/safe_yaml.rb:31:in` safe_load'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:486:in `block (2 levels) in read_checksums' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:485:in` wrap'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:485:in `block in read_checksums' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:116:in` seek'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:484:in `read_checksums' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:537:in` block (2 levels) in verify'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:29:in `new' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:536:in` block in verify'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `open' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in` with_read_io'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:535:in `verify' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:516:in` spec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:307:in `spec_from_gem' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:368:in` block in cached_specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:366:in `each' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:366:in` cached_specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:90:in `specs' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:274:in` block (2 levels) in index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:272:in `each' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:272:in` block in index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/index.rb:11:in `build' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:269:in` index'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:259:in `resolve' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in` specs'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `resolve_remotely!' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:287:in` resolve_if_needed'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:83:in `block in run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:12:in` block in lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in `open' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/process_lock.rb:9:in` lock'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:72:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bun DEBUG [93166736]   dler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/installer.rb:25:in` install'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:65:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:224:in` block in install'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/settings.rb:136:in `temporary' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:223:in` install'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in` invoke_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in` dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in` start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in` with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/bundler-1.16.6/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in` load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in` eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `'

Comment: Quite the same problem discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70775639/failed-to-install-gems-via-bundler-in-heroku-with-gemfile-lock-from-windows/70778146#70778146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I looked for the Gem that is adding Psych Gem (it is not listed in Gemfile directly). Then I restricted that parent Gem's version to previous version that does not download Psych.
Then I ran `gem uninstall psych` on the server where I was deploying the code. Removed all versions of Psych from that server.
Then the deployment worked fine.